# MVC and Entity Framework Key

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am new to MVC and EF and am having a heck of a time getting an EF query to work, specifically with the EF key="". After adding some test code, the error being returned here is 'The name idAddress does not exist in the current context'. There is a primary key on the Address table named idAddress - identty int

I have read through many suggestions on the site and can't get past this.

```
    private motion_care_360Entities db = new motion_care_360Entities();
    public ActionResult GetItems(GridParams g)
    {
        var list = db.Addresses.Include("AddressCountry").Include("AddressState").Include("AddressType").AsQueryable();
        var list1 = list.OrderBy(o => idAddress).ToList();
        var l1 = list1[0].AddressState.State;

        return Json(new GridModelBuilder<Address>(list, g)
            {
                Key = "idAddress", // needed when using Entity Framework, usually it's Id
                                   // If you're using EF, it's needed so that the data will be ordered by it before paging it
                Map = o => new
                {
                    AddressTypeType = o.AddressType.Type,
                    AddressStateState = o.AddressState.State,
                    AddressCountryCountry = o.AddressCountry.Country,
                    o.City,
                }
            }.Build());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That would need to be `list.OrderBy(o => o.idAddress).ToList();`

You need to specify that it's by the idAddress of the object (i.e. `o` from your lambda expression) itself.

Comment: Thank you....          var list1 = list.OrderBy(o => idAddress).ToList(); and var l1 = list1[0].AddressState.State; were for testing. var list is fed into the JSON code. The JSON code returns the error of '... 0 count...' as no records are being found. Am I querying the EF correctly using  var list = db.Addresses.Include("AddressCountry").Include("AddressState").Include("AddressType").AsQueryable();? It doesn't appear to return anything for the JSON to consume?

Comment: Try using `.ToList()` instead of `AsQueryable()` and see if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually confused about a lot of things.  First, the issue you claim you have has nothing to do with either MVC or EF.  It has to do with whatever GridModelBuilder is, and since that's not a part of MVC, you must be using some third party control for that.

Second, I'm guessing (since I don't know what third party control you're using) that Key is used when using GroupBy, not when using OrderBy.  OrderBy does not have a key, but GroupBy does.  But it's hard to know, since you seem to think that third party tools are part of the framework.

Third, your OrderBy is assigned to list1, which you never use.  You use list, which is unordered.

Fourth, you don't need AsQueryable as it's already a Queryable.